# Why can I not access the data from my query?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

```
        $threads = Thread::leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'threads.user_id')
        ->leftjoin('users as poster','poster.id', '=', 'threads.user_id')
        ->leftjoin('forums_threads', 'forums_threads.thread_id','=','threads.id')
        ->leftjoin('threads_users', 'threads_users.thread_id','=','threads.id');

        if($request->search){
            echo 'Search:' . $request->search;
            $threads->where('title', '=', $request->search);
        }

        if($request->author){
            echo 'author:' . $request->author;
            $threads->where('users.id', $request->author);
        }

        if($request->site){
            echo 'site:' . $request->site;
            $threads->where('threads.source', $request->site);
        }

        $threads->groupBy(array('threads.id', 'users.username','threads_users.boosts', 'users.id'))
        ->get(array('threads.*','users.username','threads_users.boosts'));
```

If I do a ->count() on it, I get a return of 3 which is what I expect.  If I do a ->toSql() I see the expected sql statement.  However if I do something like foreach($threads as $thread){ echo 'inside';} I get nothing displayed.

Comment: please do print_r($threads) to see in what array index or in what object you are getting data. then loop it.

Comment: You might want to do `$temp = $threads->where('title', '=', $request->search);` and then all subsequent calls as `$temp = $temp->where('users.id', $request->author);` as well as `$temp->get()`

Comment: Amit Shah - When I do the print_r I get what I believe is the complete model object.  It has a ton of unrelated items in it and crashes my browser it's so big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't storing the results in your `$threads` variable.

Either do this:

```
$threads = $threads->groupBy(array('threads.id', 'users.username','threads_users.boosts', 'users.id'))
    ->get(array('threads.*','users.username','threads_users.boosts'));
```

Or create a new variable and loop through that:

```
$results = $threads->groupBy(array('threads.id', 'users.username','threads_users.boosts', 'users.id'))
    ->get(array('threads.*','users.username','threads_users.boosts'));

foreach ($results as $result) {
    // stuff
}
```